# Kotlin annotation with optional parameters

Tags: kotlin, annotations

Custom annotation is defined below:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)    
annotation class Custom(val a: String, 
        val b: String = "[null]", 
        val c: String = "[null]")
```

Desired usage:

1.

```
@Custom(a = "Testa", b = "Testb", c = "Testc")
fun xyz(){ ... }
```

2.

```
@Custom(a = "Testa")
fun pqr(){ ... }
```

When I am trying desired usage #2, it throws `No values passed for parameter "b"`.

How can it be achieved to have optional parameters in kotlin cusotm annotations?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine at https://pl.kotl.in/35AFvlxE_.

Comment: so weird. My intellij IDE is showing error and performing a gradle build also, its failing. Even checked kotlin version: 1.3.21. This is beyond my understanding now.

Comment: Report the bug, I guess? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Sorry. RIP myself. Such a big mistake. I was configuring another parameter for default and was removing required parameter which I thought was set as optional. I have noted it as one of the dumbest and silliest things I have in my lifetime. Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Can you submit the code snippet shared in the link as answer. I will accept it. This will help others to quickly reproduce also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as is, which can be verified by

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)    
annotation class Custom(val a: String, 
        val b: String = "[null]", 
        val c: String = "[null]")

object W {
    @Custom(a = "Testa")
    fun pqr(){}
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(W::class.java.getMethod("pqr").getAnnotations()[0])
}
```

printing `@Custom(b=[null], c=[null], a=Testa)`, so `b` and `c` got their default values. (You could also write `W::pqr.annotations[0]`, but that doesn't work on the playground.)